# How to mock a function within a python script tested with pytest-console-scripts?

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

I need to test some legacy code, among which there are a number of Python scripts.
By script I mean Python code not within a class or module, just within a unique file and executed with `python script.py`

Here is a example `oldscript.py`:

```
import socket


def testfunction():
    return socket.gethostname()


def unmockable():
    return "somedata"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    result = testfunction()
    result = unmockable()
    print(result)
```

I'm using `pytest-console-scripts` to test this as it's "inprocess" launcher makes it possible to actually mock some things.

AFAIU, there's no way to mock any call made within a Python script when it is ran with `subprocess`

`pytest-console-scripts` makes this possible, and indeed mocks to external functions work.

Here's a test case for the above :

```
import socket
from pytest_console_scripts import ScriptRunner
from pytest_mock import MockerFixture


class TestOldScript:

    def test_success(self, script_runner: ScriptRunner, mocker: MockerFixture) -> None:
        mocker.patch('socket.gethostname', return_value="myhostname")
        mocker.patch('oldscript.unmockable', return_value="mocked!", autospec=True)
        ret = script_runner.run('oldscript.py', print_result=True, shell=True)
        socket.gethostname.assert_called_with()
        assert ret.success
        assert ret.stdout == 'mocked!'
        assert ret.stderr is None
```

This is failing as `unmockable` cannot be mocked this way.

The call to `socket.gethostname()` can be successfully mocked, but can the `unmockable` function be mocked? That is my issue.

Would there be another strategy to test such Python scripts and be able to mock internal functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that when the script is executed, `oldscript.py` is not being imported into `oldscript` namespace, it's instead in `__main__` (that's why the condition of the `if` at the bottom of the script is true). Your code successfully patchess `oldscript.unmockable`, but the script is calling `__main__.unmockable` and that one is indeed unmockable.

I see two ways to get around this:

You can split the code that you would like to mock into another module that's imported by the main script. For example if you split `oldscript.py` into two files like this:

`lib.py`:

```
def unmockable():
    return "somedata"
```

`oldscript.py`:

```
import socket
import lib


def testfunction():
    return socket.gethostname()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    result = testfunction()
    print('testfunction:', result)
    result = lib.unmockable()
    print('unmockable:', result)
```

then you can mock `lib.unmockable` in the test and everything works as expected.

Another approach is to use a `console_scripts` entry point in `setup.py` (see [here](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html#the-console-scripts-entry-point) for more info on this). This is a more sophisticated approach that would be a good fit for python packages that have `setup.py` and are installed (e.g. via `pip`).

When you set up your script to be installed and called this way, it becomes available in the `PATH` as e.g. `oldscript` and then you can call it from tests with:

```
script_runner.run('oldscript')  # Without the .py
```

These installed console scripts are imported and executed using a wrapper that `setup.py` creates, so `oldscript.py` would be imported as `oldscript` and again mocking will work.

Comment: Enlightening! I def. need to better understand Python's namespaces.

As a general rule, I like to be able to test scripts before I start to modify them. So I like the second approach better, even if it takes creating a `setup.py`. 
Though, refactoring a couple of functions to an external lib/helper should be safe, it creates the potential for an error that would be much unwelcomed in procuction...

Comment: I agree. When adding tests to scripts that didn't have tests before, not being to able to mock before moving things around could be a significant limitation. It's probably possible to mock things inside of `__main__` namespace once it's created but it would involve some special hackery. Maybe one day I'll figure out how to add this to pytest-console-scripts.